# Take sum of dynamic number of columns in SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, proc-sql, datastep

So I have a data box, as follows:

```
Obs  ID     A         B             C           D

1    X1     1         .             .           . 
2    X2     1         1             .           . 
3    X3     .         1             1           . 
4    X4     .         1             .           . 
5    X5     .         1             .           . 
6    X6     1         .             .           . 
7    X7     1         1             .           . 
8    X8     1         1             .           . 
9    X9     .         .             1           . 
10   X10    1         1             .           .
```

The objective here is to take a sum of the columns i.e

```
Total=sum(A,B,C,D)
```

But the problem here is that the number and names of the columns will not be fixed. Therefore, I wanted to create an array which would dynamically store the names of the columns, drop the id column and then wanted to take a sum of the rest. Therefore I wrote a command as follows:

```
proc sql noprint; 
  select
    name into: cols    
  from dictionary.columns
  where
    memname = 'box';quit;
```

But I get an error as follows:

```
Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

I'm sure this is not the best way to solve this problem, can anybody help me as to how should I go about it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If the columns to be summed always form a contiguous block within the column order, you can do `sum(of a--d)`.

Comment: Here's a list of ways you can shorten that method of listisng: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/05/29/6-easy-ways-to-specify-a-list-of-variables-in-sas.html

Comment: Hi User667489..the column names will be dynamic not necessarily in that order.

Comment: The metadata values for `LIBNAME` and  `MEMNAME` returned by `DICTIONARY.*` tables is always UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! The colon should be before the variable after `into`, and you will want to separate them by a comma. Try this instead:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name 
    into :cols separated by ','  
    from dictionary.columns
    where upcase(memname) = 'BOX'
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: HI Stu, Thanks for the answer. But when I write %put &cols. - I get WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference COLS not resolved. Any Idea why?